# Textmate, automatically closing indentation when closing html tag

Tags: textmate

I love Textmate, but this is a small oddity that always bothered me.

I am currently using Version 1.5.10.

I use `Command + Option + Dot` to close a html tag, but when I do the result is this.

```
<html>
  </html>
```

I wish Textmate knew how to do this instead. Automatically de-indents when closing tag is added.

```
<html>
</html>
```

This works well for Ruby code by the way. Textmate de-indents when `end` is typed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Insert Close Tag (⌘⌥.)` command in TextMate (along with every other command in the Bundles menu) is completely customisable through the `Bundle Editor`.

If you open up the Bundle Editor ( `Bundles` > `Bundle Editor` > `Show Bundle Editor (⌃⌘⌥B)`), and find the 'Insert Close Tag' command in the list on the left, you should be able to view and edit the code in that command.

To implement your un-indenting functionality, find this chunk of code (at the end of the file):

```
else
    print "</#{stack.pop}>"
end
```

And modify it so that it looks like this:

```
else
    print "</#{stack.pop}>"
    %x{ osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to key code 33 using command' }
end
```

This extra line of code tells TextMate that after inserting the closing tag, it should perform the `Shift Left` command, by simulating the a press of the key combination `⌘[` - thus un-indenting your code.